# GCD differences in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I was studying `Grand Central Dispatch` when I noticed Swift 3 changed its syntax.

So, is this:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

        let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.imageView1.image = img1
        })   
    }
```

any different from this one?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [weak self]

            () -> Void in

            let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                ()->Void in

                self?.imageView1.image = img1
            }

        }
```

Should I create a variable to contain `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside not weakifying `self` in the first approach, both calls are equivalent.

Whether or not to create a variable is up to your (convenience) preferences and does not make a difference technically.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 brings many improvements to Grand Central Dispatch syntax and usage.

Previously, we would choose the dispatch method (sync vs async) and then the queue we wanted to dispatch our task to. The updated GCD reverses this order - we first choose the queue and then apply a dispatch method.

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: [.qosDefault]).async { 
    // Background thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
        // UI Updates
    })
}
```

### Queue attributes

You will notice that queues now take attributes on init. This is a Swift OptionSet and can include queue options such as serial vs concurrent, memory and activity management options and the quality of service (.default, .userInteractive, .userInitiated, .utility and .background).
The quality of service replaces the old priority attributes that were deprecated in iOS8. If you were used to priority queues, here’s how they map over to QOS cases:

```
* DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH:         .userInitiated
* DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT:      .default
* DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW:          .utility
* DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND:   .background
```

### Work items

Queues are not the only part of GCD to get a Swift OptionSet. There’s an updated Swift syntax for work items too:

```
let workItem = DispatchWorkItem(qos: .userInitiated, flags: .assignCurrentContext) {
    // Do stuff
}
queue.async(execute: workItem)
```

A work item can now declare a quality or service and/or flags on init. Both of these are optional and affect the execution of the work item.

### dispatch_once

`dispatch_once` was very useful for initialisation code and other functions that were to be executed once and only once.
In Swift 3, dispatch_once is deprecated and should be replaced with either global or static variables and constants.

```
// Examples of dispatch_once replacements with global or static constants and variables. 
// In all three, the initialiser is called only once. 

// Static properties (useful for singletons).
class Object {
    static let sharedInstance = Object()
}

// Global constant.
let constant = Object()

// Global variable.
var variable: Object = {
    let variable = Object()
    variable.doSomething()
    return variable
}()
```

### dispatch_assert

Also new in this year’s Apple OS releases are dispatch preconditions. These replace dispatch_assert and allow you to check whether or not you are on the expected thread before executing code. This is particularly useful for functions that update the UI and must be executed on the main queue. Here’s a simple example:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosUserInitiated)
let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main

mainQueue.async {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .notOnQueue(mainQueue))
    // This code won't execute
}

queue.async {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(queue))
    // This code will execute
}
```

---

Source: https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/a-quick-look-at-gcd-and-swift-3-732bef6e1838#.7hdtfwxb4